# Visual studio 2019 do not want to produce ASM files for LIB release, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2019

I'm using this command line:

```
/permissive- /MP /GS- /Qpar /GL /W4 /wd"4530" /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\src" 
/I"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\inc" /Gm- /Ox /Fd"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\tmp\64aRavx2\vc142" /fp:precise 
/Zp1 /D "AMD" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /fp:except- /errorReport:none /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR- 
/arch:AVX2 /Gv /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\asm\64aRavx2\" /nologo 
/Fo"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\tmp\64aRavx2\" /FAcs /Ot /diagnostics:column /Ob3 /favor:AMD64
```

to compile LIB project in VS 2019 and "C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\asm\64aRavx2\" stays empty. But it's being created during compile time.

If I switch to Debug settings:

```
/JMC /permissive- /MP /GS- /W4 /wd"4530" /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\src" 
/I"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\inc" /ZI /Gm- /Od /Fd"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\tmp\64aDavx2\vc142" /fp:precise 
/Zp1 /D "AMD" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /fp:except- /errorReport:none /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR- 
/arch:AVX2 /Gv /MDd /FC /Fa"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\asm\64aDavx2\" /nologo 
/Fo"C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\tmp\64aDavx2\" /FAcs /diagnostics:column /Ob3 /favor:AMD64
```

or, if I'm switching project type from LIB to EXE, correspondig folder being filled with ".asm" files as usual.
Compiler won't generate asm files only for Static Library Release versions of the same code.

What I'm doing wrong or how to determine what's the problem is in?

BTW, output produces no errors in any of the ways:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: oLib, Configuration: Release - AVX2 64 AMD ------
1>lib.cpp
1>oLib.vcxproj -> C:\oTemplates\oLib\oLib\bin\oLib64aRavx2.lib
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Looks like you created your own configurations beyond the standard Debug and Release.  That's okay but a bit risky, you might be reading back the compile options of one (like "Release") but building with the settings of another (like "Release - AVX2 64 AMD").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone will be interested:

For LIB projects, it's required to remove /GL option ("Configuration Properties"->"C/C++"->"Optimization"->"Whole Program Optimization") to produce .asm files.